# How many (super)villains have managed to get into the Batcave?

Tags: dc, batman

Having gone through a few questions asked here, it seems the Joker ([Has the Joker ever been inside the Batcave?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95187/has-the-joker-ever-been-inside-the-batcave/95189#95189)) has never been in the Batcave, but Catwoman has ([Has Catwoman been to the Batcave before New 52?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109780/has-catwoman-been-to-the-batcave-before-new-52?rq=1)). It made me wonder how many other (super-) villains have managed to get into the Batcave (Silver Age)?

Comment: Technically speaking, Catwoman has been in the Batcave not only as a villain. :P

Comment: Some copy-pasting can be done from [15 Villains Who Broke Into The Batcave](https://screenrant.com/batman-rogues-villains-that-broke-into-the-batcave/), if anyone feels like it. Although, among others, _SPOILERS FOR "THE BUTTON" ARC_ Reverse-Flash _END SPOILERS_ is missing from that list.

Comment: Is it just comics? IIRC, King Tut broke into the Batcave.

Comment: I think that Ra's Al Ghul did during the Hush storyline and left a sword stabbed in a Batcave computer. Or maybe this was during "Bruce Wayne: Murderer"

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. "All media acceptable" equates to hundreds of comic serials (probably more than 10-20,000 individual issues), dozens of films, prose novels, TV shows and etc.

Comment: Better. Still really broad, but answerable.

Answer (score -3):

In the LEGO multiverse in Lego Batman 2, The Joker and Lex Luthor break into the Batcave and use there anti black stuff ray to destroy a bunch of stuff.

In Batman Arkham origins Bane breaks into the Batcave and destroys Batman's computers then somehow injures Alfred and puts a boulder on top of him (the boulder bit you don't see, though its just after you return in the batwing and see the Bat-cave terminals all broken.

In the animated movie of "Batman vs Robin" the court of owls break into the Batcave and Batman and Nightwing fight them off with "quite the troubles" at not being able to stop them.

Comment: This isn't even close to being comprehensive, but then again, the question is so broad that a comprehensive answer would be almost impossible, which is why it was closed shortly after you posted this.

Comment: The edit to the question has now also invalidated this answer (it's looking for Silver Age instances, and none of these are Silver Age)

Comment: @F1Krazy - Given that it's carrying downvotes, it would probably be better to be reposted as a self-answer to a new question if OP wants to salvage it. This is what happens when people answer questions that are off-topic.